# C - making hash function for int triples

Tags: c, hash

I need to implement some sort of set data structure for triples of this kind:
(int, int, int), where first 2 ints are from unknown range and third int is usually small. I don't need any information about ordering, so I decded to use HashSet. I've never implemented anything like it but I've read it's really easy to mess it up and have bad performance when using it.

Here's what I plan to do. I make a big array of resizeable buckets and (hash function % size) gives the number of the bucket to put the triple in. I know I need to use all buckets evenly in order for it to be efficient. The question is: what is the right way to do this? Is "(a+b+c) mod size" efficient enough or I need to use something more complex?

Comment: `a + b + c` is obviously a very bad choice, since *any permutation* of values will have the same hash. Generally, you want to mix all the ingredient bits as much as possible. Do some reasearch on general hash functions, and then apply a sensbile algorithm to all your constituent bits.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1362712/2697007

Comment: Note that you still have to make provisions for different value having the same hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use trivial hash functions because the dispersion is far from optimal and the probability of collisions is high. Hash functions has been object of many studies, and you should first start at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#List_of_hash_functions) - for your usage, you should considere non cryptographic one.

If unsure, the FNV-1a hash is generally considered as correct (extract from wikipedia) :

```
hash = FNV_offset_basis
for each byte_of_data to be hashed
     hash = hash XOR byte_of_data
     hash = hash × FNV_prime
return hash
```

if you want 32 bit hashes, the prime is 2<sup>24</sup> + 2<sup>8</sup> + 0x93 = 16777619

What is nice is that the product can be written as a small number of shift and additions :

```
hval += (hval<<1) + (hval<<4) + (hval<<7) + (hval<<8) + (hval<<24);
```

Rerefences : [FNV Hash](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/)

Comment: "What is nice is that the product can be written as shift and additions" Isn't that true for any multiplication;-)? It can be optimized if the number of buckets is a power of two, however.

Comment: @Olaf I should have said *a small number of shifts...* - post edited

Comment: For a CPU with multiplier that makes things very likely worse, For a small MCU, it might help. But these seldom need 32 bit hashes. I appreciate your thoughts, however.

Comment: @Olaf On the pages I reference, you can find some implémentations for hashes of different size. And the *optimisation* is optional...

Comment: I know the FNV hash pretty well. It was used for Python long time in a modified version before they [changed to SipHash](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0456/). I personallyy like its simplicity and speed. If you do not have to worry about attacks, i think it is an excellent choice for many applications.